# Android Adapter Fragment

Tags: android, adapter

Как сделать смену фрагмента в адаптере ?

Сделать клик на CardView - сделал

Но при попытки сменить активность он не может найти метод "getSupportFragmentManager", "getFragmentManager" так же не ищет

Код приведен снизу

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private View mView;
private CardView cardView;

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

        cardView = mView.findViewById(R.id.main_blog_post);
    }

}




@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Bread", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

Сам метод

```
    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Правильно будет, если адаптер будет делегировать событие клика внешнему обработчику, который будет името доступ к необходимым вам объектам.

Пример, как можно такое сделать:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ListAdapter<MyObject, MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private OnMyObjectClickListener clickListener;

    public void setClickListener(OnMyObjectClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public interface OnMyObjectClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, MyObject obj);
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_blog_post);
            cardView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                final int position = getAdapterPosition();
                final MyObject obj = getItem(position);
                if (clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onItemClick(position, obj);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Где-то в вашем активити/фрагменте:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
...
adapter.setClickListener((position, obj) -> {
    ... // здесь можем получить FragmentManager
});
```

PS: если вы не используете до сих пор Java8, то вместо лямбд будет немного более длинный код